# Javascript issues in Magento 2 cart page

Tags: cart, knockoutjs

In my magento 2 theme in cart page in console, I have errors:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unable to parse bindings.
Bindings value: if: getCartParam(summary_count') 
Message: missing ) after argument list
```

how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

**' is missing from the code:**

**should be like this:**

```
getCartParam('summary_count')
```

**example code from minicart.phtml:**

```
 <a class="action showcart" href="javascript:void(0);<?php //echo $block->getShoppingCartUrl(); ?>"
       data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
        <span class="text"><?php echo __('My Cart'); ?></span>
        <span class="counter qty empty"
              data-bind="css: { empty: !!getCartParam('summary_count') == false }, blockLoader: isLoading">
            <span class="counter-number">
            <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko ifnot: getCartParam('summary_count') -->0<!-- /ko -->
            </span>
            <span class="counter-label">
                <!-- ko i18n: 'items' --><!-- /ko -->
            </span>
        </span>
    </a>
```